# Function where user supplies a column name and a tbl

Tags: function, tidyverse

I had a function that previously worked where I iterated the same operations over a user input of column names that no longer works. Here's a very simplified scenario in which a user should be able to input a data.frame and a columname and the function should return an operation done on that particular column. This was working about 1 month ago.

```
df = data.frame(X1 = c(1:10), Y1=letters[1:10])
df

df %>% 
  mutate(X2=X1 * 2)


tb.test = function(tbl, column) {
  tbl2 = tbl %>%
    mutate(X2 = {{column}} * 2)
  return(tbl2)
}                                                                                   
tb.test(df, X1)
```

This no longer seems to be working with an error column X1 not found.

Comment: My guess is that the function might be trying to use `plyr` instead of `dplyr`. Try making it explicit for `mutate`. Does using `dplyr::mutate(X2 = {{column}} * 2)` solve the issue?

Comment: You're correct. The issue was a package conflict between Ipaper and Tidyverse. Once I unloaded Ipaper the function worked as intended. Good call on adding the dplyr::mutate() to avoid these conflicts.